# SQL For Loop query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, for-loop

I am newbie to SQL.

I want to insert data into table using below for-loop query.
But unable to identify the issue

```
declare
cursor mac is SELECT DISTINCT(MAC) FROM DEVICES;
cmd varchar2(200);
begin
for c in mac loop
cmd := 'INSERT INTO MAC VALUES(DEVICES_ID_SEQ.nextVal,'||c.MAC||',"ABC","123")';
execute immediate cmd;
end loop;
end;
```

For each MAC in existing table, I want to insert new record.

Comment: Don't use a cursor or PL/SQL if it's not needed, please! Look at Quassnoi's answer for something that is MUCH faster and MUCH less code. Learn to do things the set-based way using SQL.

Comment: And dynamic SQL is not needed for this case either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a cursor for that.

Just run:

```
INSERT
INTO    mac
SELECT  DEVICES_ID_SEQ.nextval, mac, 'abc', 123
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                mac
        FROM    devices
        )
```

Comment: Another great example of less is more. The OP 1) uses dynamic SQL (not needed); 2) probably has a bug with the MAC address being a string and therefore should be quoted in the dynamic SQL; 3) is somewhat susceptible to overflowing the string buffer of just 200 characters; 4) uses PL/SQL and a cursor where it's not needed anyway.